# How to call Model class inside a normal php file?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Im using a codeigniter framework. I just want to know if it is possible to call a class that extends Model inside a normal php file. If it is possible, then how? thnx in advance for the response.

Comment: What's a `normal` PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.  A model is just a PHP class.  Say for example you have

```
class Blogmodel extends CI_Model {
    ...
}
```

You could just do in your .php file

```
include 'path/to/blogmodel.php';
$blogModel = new Blogmodel();

$result = $blogModel->some_function();
```